# From where to use TokenHelper class for client context in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I have been reading several articles to get SharePoint Online client context with the generated access token. All of them use `TokenHelper` class to get the client context as shown below:

```
ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(targetWeb, AccessToken);
```

My question is how do we access `TokenHelper` class? I could not find it in the reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` version 16.1.0.0. What reference do we need to add to access this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get answer from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/223245/68997). In case anyone needs it in future, below is the answer:

Just add the NuGet package `AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit`. It will add the `TokenHelper.cs` and `SharePointContext.cs` files to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the below NuGet package in your solution:

**--> AppForSharePointWebToolkit**

[image]

Installation will add the following files & references to your solution :
[image]

For more information:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AppForSharePointWebToolkit/

**Please Note:**

1. ***AppForSharePointWebToolkit*** is for SharePoint 2013
2. If you are working on SharePoint 2016 or working on Visual Studio 2017 you have to install ***AppForSharePoint16WebToolkit***

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any NuGet packages or other external sources as long you work with *Visual Studio* and you have the [Office developer Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/26/the-latest-of-microsoft-office-developer-tools-office-add-in-commands-and-sharepoint-2016-support/) and [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585) installed, just as written in the [forum thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/223242/6919) you referred to.

Simply create a new project, and select the *SharePoint Add-in* project template from *Installed / Visual C# / Office/SharePoint / Add-ins* hive. On the first page of the project wizard select the *Provider-hosted* option (I think it is the default one), and on the second page select *SharePoint Online* if you want to work with O365. The `TokenHelper.cs` will be included in the project generated by *Visual Studio*.

See these tutorials for more details:

- [Create high-trust SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-high-trust-sharepoint-add-ins#to-create-a-high-trust-sharepoint-add-in)
- [How to Create a High-Trust, Provider-Hosted Add-In?](http://www.sohodragon.nyc/2017/12/11/create-high-trust-provider-hosted-add-in/)
- [Get started creating provider-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins#create-the-add-in-project)
- [Step by Step approach to create a Provider Hosted Application in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-approach-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013)